# Resize Debian 9 boot partition

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian

I would like to resize from 923G to 500G.

[image]

Comment: Filesystem type is ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui  ext4

Comment: can you boot from another OS or live CD/DVD/USB ?

Comment: yes but not at the moment

Comment: Then, your best option is boot from live Linux in CD/USB and use gparted/resizefs/... to reduce the filesystem and resize the partition. Disclaimer: make backup, etc, etc.

Comment: Please do not post terminal text as a screenshot.

Comment: @bertieb tried to use gparted but the resize button is not active

Comment: @melebius noted

Comment: @ryanmunene That information should be in the question (you can [edit it to include it](https://superuser.com/posts/1307966/edit)) along with anything else that might be pertinent (eg error messages if present, etc).

Comment: @Melebius - I went ahead and put the screenshot back into the question.  If you have a problem with the edit talk to a moderator. The screenshot was more helpful than no information.  There is no rule against terminal text as a screenshot, I don't understand, why you ask to have it be removed in the first place.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for the edit. I absolutely didn’t want to remove the screenshot without any compensation. The terminal text should be generally provided as text. I am sorry to give a misleading information since this time I haven’t pasted the second sentence of my usual comment for this case: _Paste the text directly to your question and apply code formatting (the `{}` icon)._

Answer (score 0):

Download the GParted ISO, burn it to a CD, boot from it, and resize the partition from there.

This is assuming of course that you have less than 500Gb data on the partition.

If you wish to use a USB pen drive rather than a CD, both UNetBootIn (https://unetbootin.github.io) and Rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie) are able to create a bootable pen drive from an ISO image, however you will probably need to reformat the pen drive with a third party utility (such as the HP Disk Storage Tool) to make the pen drive show up correctly as a removable disk rather than a hard drive again afterwards.

I would also suggest that you have a read of the following - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

People are generally very helpful on SO, however if you can provide enough information to provide a complete answer, you will likely get a response faster with more detail.

Comment: Burning a CD in 2018? IMHO USB drive is much more likely to be available as of today.

Comment: For GParted, I pretty much always use a CD. It's a small ISO, and every time I create a bootable USB pen from an ISO, I end up messing up the partition table on the pen drive so that Windows can't read it. For OS installs, the pen drive is king but for stuff like GParted, or Hiren, CDs all the way. To make a GParted live USB is much more involved than download ISO, burn ISO.

Comment: For me, it’s one more reason to not waste a CD… I have successfully installed various ISOs using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) on a flash drive also used for other things, put multiple ISOs on a single flash drive using [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)… Apart from that, an optical drive becomes rare in newer PCs.

Comment: @Melebius Generally, I do prefer using USBs for installs, but for something I use infrequently (thankful, GParted Live hasn't needed to come out much recently), I prefer not to use a USB as they get used a lot for moving data about. I tend to have a spindle of CDs most of the time, but I did also deliberately keep optical drives in my machines for that purpose. UNetBootIn is a very good call though, as is Rufus. I shall amend the answer I think...

Comment: @alex could not boot gparted.

Comment: @ryanmunene Using a USB drive or a CD?